# Get the value of the Key from a Json Array

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the below Json Array and I need to get the value of the key inside my "relation" object. How do I do that? The relation object has different set of key-value pair for each object in the array.

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "_hash": null,
            "kind": "ENTITY",
            "id": "test122",
            "payload": {
                "attributes": {
                    "bbl:27": false
                },
                "relations": {
                    "bbl:45": "P18",
                    "bbl:P18": "P562"
                },
                "type": [
                    "P185"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

In above inside relations the keys are "bbl:45" and "bbl:P18". I need these values, in specific I need to extract 45 and P18, considering bbl remain constant inside relation object. how do i do it. There are multiple objects in the Jarray, I have shown only one.

Comment: Deserialize to dynamic and search the properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would mention, if you can change data format, consider doing so, having payload as part as a member proper name is highly unusual but you could do like this:

```
    [Fact]
    public void DynamicJsonHandlingTest()
    {
        var serialized = "[{\"data\":{\"_hash\":null,\"kind\":\"ENTITY\",\"id\":\"test122\",\"payload\":{\"attributes\":{\"bbl:27\":false},\"relations\":{\"bbl:45\":\"P18\",\"bbl:P18\":\"P562\"},\"type\":[\"P185\"]}}}]";
        using var jDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(serialized);
        var enumerator = jDoc.RootElement.EnumerateArray();
        foreach(var JsonElement in enumerator)
        {
            var relationsElement = JsonElement.GetProperty("data").GetProperty("payload").GetProperty("relations");

            foreach (var ele in relationsElement.EnumerateObject())
            {
                var sought = ele.Name.Split(":")[1];
                //sought now cointains first 45 then P18
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `JsonDocument` should be [disposed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-6.0#remarks) after usage.

Comment: @GuruStron absolutely, just wanted to outline a solution, not provide a production ready code, also the new language feature "using var" is very useful. 
Obviously executing on a string means we have no unmanaged resources unlike what could be if using a stream or a jsonreader when it would matter more.
But sure, disposable things should be disposed, I agree

Comment: Code you post on SO is quite likely be copied as is with little to none modification, with high chance of such thing as lacking using being missed, so it is better to do everything as correctly as possible. Especially the change being as small as adding `using`.

Comment: Also please read the linked docs - you need to dispose regardless using or not the stream due to the nature of inner implementation of `JsonDocument`

Comment: @GuruStron Software quality is a personal responsibility and dedication to my mind, belongs with the personal software process, and uncritical copy/ paste is no part of that.
Though i don't mind updating the suggestion though, even if I also do chew the food for my kids, I don't buy your argument that because people will copy paste we need to do more than help solving the problems but also provide production ready code, I wouldn't call it the goal of this forum, and a quick unit test to outline a solution is all the user needed.

Comment: _"I wouldn't call it the goal of this forum"_ I think providing quality answers is a part of SO goal. And I would say missing `using` here is not very good and can be missed even by responsible, dedicated and knowledgeable developers.

Comment: @GuruStron "...and can be missed even by responsible, dedicated and knowledgeable..."
Well if according to the docs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-6.0#using-an-object-that-implements-idisposable 
We get easily the knowledge that it should be called, but will be called regardless. 

All dedicated resources, even juniors will quickly learn on their own because they consume classes that is and use code review from seniors.

Not to be splitting hairs but IMHO one can expect this quality rom developers, and I do with my team and it was never a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic keys you can use dictionary:

```
public class Root
{
     public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Payload payload { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> relations { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(sourcejson);
```

And then next will contain all keys:

```
var keys = result
    .Select(r => r.data)
    .Select(r => r.payload)
    .SelectMany(r => r.relations.Keys)
```

Or use the LINQ to JSON API:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(sourcejson);
var list = result
    .Children()
    .SelectMany(c => c["data"]["payload"]["relations"].Children<JProperty>())
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .ToList(); // list is {"bbl:45", "bbl:P18"}
```

And then you can process the keys as you need - for example using `Split(':')` to turn `"bbl:45"` into array of `"bbl"` and `"45".

Comment: one issue, The relation key is actually api:relation. and that give issue in public Dictionary<string, string> api:relations { get; set; }. How do i fix this ?

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint not following you. `relations` in the model above will have your "bbl:value" pairs as keys, you just grab all keys and parse them. What is `public Dictionary<string, string> api:relations { get; set; }` and why are you trying to add/create it somewhere?

Comment: you are right.. what i am saying is the key relation is actually "api:realtion". thats the full name and if I put it like this in public Dictionary<string, string> api:relations { get; set; } , I get error as ";" expected. how do i parse this

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint you can't parse it using json parser cause from json format "point of view" it is a "minimal" token - property name which can't be broken down into smaller pieces.  You need to extract all those pieces as strings (as done in my answer) and use `Split(':')` on them.

Comment: To my mind, this solution is overkill @GuruStron, the question is I "Have Json, how do I solve..", to invent 3 models within each other, one containing a dictionary even is ragingly inefficient and the linq doesn't end up with the result, at least split or substring on the select. 
Consider treating json as json, .net is good at that and provide many alternatives to avoid unnecessary complications. The KISS design principle springs to mind, we should always try to keep things simple, we'll need to maintain them :)

Comment: @T.Nielsen valid points, and I can agree to them. Also both do not provide the desired result  and require `Split` ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following Code solves your problem.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Json.Net;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"data\":{\"_hash\":null,\"kind\":\"ENTITY\",\"id\":\"test122\",\"payload\":{\"attributes\":{\"bbl:27\":false},\"relations\":{\"bbl:45\":\"P18\",\"bbl:P18\":\"P562\"},\"type\":[\"P185\"]}}}"; 

            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

            var results = jsonObject["data"]["payload"]["relations"];

            foreach (var item in results)
            {

                string propName = ((JProperty)item).Name;

                string requiredValue = propName.Split(':')[1];

                Console.WriteLine($"Required: {requiredValue} !");


               
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You should add some error handling when the property name does not contains `:`

Comment: mine is an an arry

Comment: This code can be modified easily to handle data in the form of array. I have kept it simple for better understanding.